# Swagger with spring MVC not generating the documentation of the services

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

i am using swagger with spring mvc, the `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and in spring configuration.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**"
    location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
```

also i use java-based configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*")).build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title(" Admin Api").description("Admin Api").version("V1")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://terms-of-services.url").license("LICENSE")
                .licenseUrl("http://url-to-license.com").build();
    }
}
```

in the controller i use

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/" })
@Api(value = "product", description = "Products Web Services") // Swagger annotation
public class ProductController {
    @ApiOperation(value = "products", nickname = "Get list of all products", response = ProductListResponse.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ProductListResponse getAllProducts(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
```

in `application.propeties` i added `springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api-docs`.
that is all information i used to generate documentation 
using the url http://localhost:8080/admin-api/admin/api-docs , it doesnt generate documentation for the end points

```
{
swagger: "2.0",
info: {
description: " Admin Api",
version: "V1",
title: "Admin Api",
termsOfService: "http://terms-of-services.url",
license: {
name: "LICENSE",
url: "http://url-to-license.com"
}
},
host: "localhost:8080",
basePath: "/admin-api/admin"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. after miss around many things i found the solution, i changed the method `Docket api()` to be

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
```

i think the the part `PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*")` on the old method was restricting the lookup process of the end points